# Raster stack does not seem to want to read file

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, terra, rgdal

Im trying to put several raster files (.tif) into one stack using the stack function from the raster package. As i do this i run into two errors, namely:

```
> covStack <- stack(paste0(getwd(),"/", cov.lst))
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
In addition: Warning message:
`C:\Users\"fileway"\jbas_14.tif.vat.cpg' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)
```

The code that I am trying to run is the following:

```
setwd(file.path("C:/Users/..."))

library(raster)
library(RSAGA) 
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(terra)

cov.lst <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern =".tif")

covStack <- stack(paste0(getwd(),"/", cov.lst))
```

I have tried reinstalling all versions of R and all the packages aswell and individually installing only the packages that are needed and their dependencies. I have also tried `unlink(".RData")`. Further I have tried using the `rast` function in `terra` aswell which returns the same errors.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Please change `pattern` in `list.files()` to list `.tif` files only, like: `cov.lst <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern =".tif$")`. Otherwise cov.lst will contain `*.tif.vat.cpg` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems clear enough

```
C:\Users\"fileway"\jbas_14.tif.vat.cpg' not recognized as a supported file format
```

To only use the files that *end on* tif you can add the `$` sign to the pattern

```
cov.lst <- list.files(pattern =".tif$")
```

And now you can do

```
s <- raster::stack(cov.lst)
```

Or use terra instead

```
r <- terra::rast(cov.lst)
```